# ubuntu some programs look very small

Tags: display, 20.04, gimp

hello there i have installed gimp , pinta , maltego , and for some reason all of them have very small interface that you can't work with it at all you can't see the tool bar while other applications like vs code and android studio looks just fine what is the problem and how i can fix it ?

note : i have 125% display scale because my display 14 inch 
here is a photo of gimp and i ust ubuntu 20 LTS

[image]

Comment: What you don't tell it that you have a high-definition screen. For Gimp there are themes with large fonts and icons (but some stuff remain small, like pointers). For the other apps I don't know. Maybe your window manager can scale windows for some applications.

Comment: do you have any solution in mind ? gimp is unusable

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/79118/gimp-how-do-i-change-ui-dpi